# Magento block type

Tags: magento, block

In magento blocks what does block type means as in the below block?

```
<block type="core/template" template="example/view.phtml" />
```

Please help me in learning magento module development.

Is there some good resource?

Comment: The Magento Developer API's are right here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: The Magento API is a layer that sits on top of the normal Magento system and offers a (mostly) stable set of methods to call via SOAP, RPC, etc.  It's an abstraction ABOVE the base PHP code that Sohail is trying to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The block "type" is a PHP Class.  In a normal system, a

```
core/template
```

block type will become a Mage_**Core**_Block_**Template** class.

As for resources, [start here](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers) (self link)

Comment: I have one more question, if all I want to include .phtml file which will contain some code, I want to include this file in the right of the page. What block type would I use?

Comment: You'd use a core/template block.  The type of the block and the area of the page that a block shows up in are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I learnt -

type refers to the PHP file that will provide the methods for this phtml. Examaple:

/app/code/local/modstorm/Block/Filename.php , where all your methods for this block resides. So if, for example, you are have something like $this->getMethodName() in your .phtml, you must have getMethodName() function declared in /app/code/local/modstorm/block/Filename.php.

Hope this helps others as well.